# Find element with java stream if not present choose another

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java stream,

I have a list of data which has some priority
it look like this

```
triggerFilterList =  [{"id":"1","name":"xyz":"rank":"1","priority":"A-1"},
{"id":"1","name":"xyz":"rank":"1","priority":"A-2"},
{"id":"1","name":"xyz":"rank":"1","priority":"A-3"},
{"id":"1","name":"xyz":"rank":"2","priority":"NA"}]
```

Currently this is what I have done, in this scenario I am getting only first element

```
TriggerEntity triggerEntity = triggerFilterList.stream()
    .filter(triggerData -> triggerData.getRank().equalsIgnoreCase(RankCategoryModel.getRank())
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

I need to fetch data which has priority 1 if rank is 1, if priority 1 not present then get priority 2 data  if priority 2 is not present then get priority 3 data,
In some cases priority will not be available.

In this `triggerEntity` I need data priority wise

Comment: So you want to *sort* the stream.

Comment: no, if priority 1 is available then I need only this line
`{"id":"1","name":"xyz":"rank":"1","priority":"1"}`
if priority 2 is available then I need only this line
`{"id":"1","name":"xyz":"rank":"1","priority":"2"}`

Comment: And you achieve that by sorting the stream, after which the first element will be the one you want.

Comment: You should sort, take the first entry from the result and loop thru the list until priority <> previous priority.

Comment: If possible values are (1, 2,.... NA), you can achieve it by comparing lexicographically: `triggerFilterList.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(TriggerEntity::getRank)).orElse(null);`

Comment: @Kayaman will sorting work for `A-2` this kind of data

Comment: @Rigsby sorting is the "list iteration" approach, the stream one is given above... If you have custom values, use custom comparator.

Comment: It will work, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is this what you want but when i read your explanation sounds something like this works;

```
triggerFilterList.stream()
            .reduce( (trigerredData1, trigerredData2) ->
                trigerredData1.rank.equals(trigerredData1.priority) ? trigerredData1 : trigerredData2);
```